# Why was this CUDA/OpenCL question off topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm a little miffed about the closure on this question, and can only assume the votes came from people who know nothing about the tagged subjects of CUDA and OpenCL. However, I may be wrong.

Both CUDA and OpenCL are commonly used to perform highly parallel computing tasks, by offloading the processing to GPUs and taking advantage of their high numbers of simple cores.

As such, a question about availability of specialist hardware (such as a motherboard supporting high numbers of graphics cards and hence GPU cores) seems bang on topic to me.

So, is there anything I can do to salvage the question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087920/are-there-dedicated-motherboards-for-large-numbers-of-graphics-cards?noredirect=1#comment50192985_31087920

Comment: Doesn't the text say it all? `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: It might be a good question for the related chat room though

Comment: @pekka Thanks, I'll try the chat room - I'd dispute that I've asked for any of those recommendations; it seems that the first 4 close votes came from people that don't seem to follow CUDA/OpenCL.

Comment: Being intimately familiar with the topic, I would have also closed it. It's a clear cut recommendation question that is off-topic for Stack Overflow. So whether or not the closers have any CUDA/OpenCL activities, they were correct.

Comment: It is a bit worrisome that a 5K rep SO user cannot see that a non-programming related shopping question is off topic.  Frankly, quacks like a case of sour-grapes.

Answer (score 4):

The general consensus is that *any* "Is there a...?" type questions are off topic.

I agree it's not an optimal state of affairs in specialist topics as this one, but imagine the flurry of garbage it would cause in other tags if allowed  ("Is there a jQuery gallery that does x?")

Comment: yeah the review process on SO is in a sorry state. People ought to show some qualification on the topic before they can actually vote to close it - such as having answered a question with the same tags that has been upvoted at least once.

Comment: @miraculixx why? The question in, err, question was clearly off-topic; you don't always need to be a domain expert to determine that (and that wouldn't be helpful for mis-tagged questions, either).

Comment: @jonrsharpe because asking "are there motherboards for large numbers of graphics cards" is a valid question if you know what you are talking about, where as "is there a book on graphics cards" is not. semantics matter or at least should matter more than the actual wording.

Comment: @miraculixx but neither is on-topic on Stack Overflow, and **you don't have to be a CUDA expert to know that**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe see, if you were a CUDA expert you would at least understand the OP's slant on the question which made it on-topic because he was not inquiring about comparing hardware, but about _how to run software_ efficiently on specialised hardware. never mind, the question has been deleted by now so our discussion is kind of moot.